# Export PDF from crystal Report

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports, export-to-pdf

I am generating crystal reports on a particular `Invoice No` entered by user. The Crystal Report is successfully `exported` as `PDF` in `SampleInvoice.pdf` for the first time but when I generate another Crystal report at the same time, the new one doesn't get `Exported` and `SampleInvoice.pdf` remains same.

This is how I generate Crystal Report

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source=.;Initial catalog=InvoiceSystem;user id =sa;password=rfm");
        con.Open();
       // string query = "Select * from tblInvoice";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("sp_Report", con);
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtInvoice.Text;
        con.Close();
        InvoiceDataSet DS = new InvoiceDataSet();
        da.Fill(DS, "tblInvoice");
        con.Close();
        rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport3.rpt"));
        rpt.SetDataSource(DS);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        ExportPDf();
```

This is how I am exporting PDF

```
        string filepath = "E:\\SampleInvoice.pdf";
        public void ExportPDf()
        {
           ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
           DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
           PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
           CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = filepath;
           CrExportOptions = rpt.ExportOptions;//Report document  object has to be given here
           CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
           CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
           CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
           CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
           rpt.Export();
     }
```

**Is there any way I can clear my PDF as soon as I generate another one?**

Comment: Isn't the file being overwrited? Does the code throw an exception?

Comment: I would like to suggest you to keep the file name unique so, when the existing file is elusively open by you or another user then it wont throw the errror. ie. SampleInvoice_2015_06_28_13_27_59.pdf